# How can I manage the document version history synced to local file server with SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, onedrive, file-server

I would like to migrate local file server with SharePoint online document system and I would like to use both of them synced. if there is a number of version of document exists on SharePoint then how can I sync all the version of document with local file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office automatically saves versions of your SharePoint, OneDrive, and OneDrive for Business files while you’re working on them.

You can sync your SharePoint files to a folder on your computer where you can work directly in File Explorer using OneDrive sync client.

When you open the file in the local computer, you can also view historical versions of the file.

[How to view historical versions of Office files](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2)

Note: Version history in Office only works for files stored in OneDrive or SharePoint Online. If you don't see this option it's possible your file is stored in a different service or on a local device.